# How come a table td width is not equal to a tr width?

Tags: html, css

So I have this simple table markup:

```html
    <table style="border:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:288px">
      <tr style="padding:0;border:none;margin:0">
        <td style="padding:0;border:none;margin:0;width:288px;">
          <div style="width:288px;margin:0;padding:0;border:none;">xx</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

The div and td tag return a width of 288 in the Chrome inspector as expected.  However the tr and table are returning 292.  Where are the those 4 extra pixels coming from?

I'm trying to get a pixel precise table to be the same with as the td.  Any thoughts?

Comment: In Chrome's web inspector have a look at the applied styles for the `<td>` elements, perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS table default padding or margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541765/css-table-default-padding-or-margin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a "border-collapse: collapse;" style to your table.

In standard HTML, the property is set to "separate", adding an (unwanted here) padding to your table.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
<table style="border:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:288px;-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing:0;">
  <tr style="padding:0;border:none;margin:0">
    <td style="padding:0;border:none;margin:0;width:288px;">
      <div style="width:288px;margin:0;padding:0;border:none;">xx</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases setting the following css on the table-element will get everything to listen!

```
table-layout: fixed;
```